# array returns null outside foreach but has values inside foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array named `slideIcons`. This array is filled from inside a foreach loop like this:

```
$slideIcons = [];
foreach ($data[$key]["icons"] as $icon) {
    $slideIcons[] = $icon["preview_url"];
}
```

However, when I try to do this:

`die(var_dump(($slideIcons)`

from outside of the foreach loop (after the loop), the printed result is that it's an empty array. Which is weird, because if I run the code like this:

```
$slideIcons = [];
foreach ($data[$key]["icons"] as $icon) {
    $slideIcons[] = $icon["preview_url"];
    die(var_dump($slideIcons));
}
```

It prints:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(54) "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2300-200.png"
}
```

So it seems to be that the `$slideIcons` variable is reset somehow, however I don't see any way of that being possible.

For troubleshooting, I changed the name of the variable to be 100% certain that it isn't being overwritten, but that didn't change the outcome. I also tried to replace

`$slideIcons[] = $icon["preview_url"];`

for:

`array_push($slideIcons, $icon["preview_url"]);`

but that didn't change the outcome either. So is it possible that, for some wild reason, the variable is being reset to its base value, or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Edit:
Some more information, the `$key` variable is passed onto this function by its parent, which contains a `foreach` loop. However, this shouldn't matter, since the `$slideIcons` variable is saved into the database before it gets reset by it's parent foreach. For easy I included the full function:

```
 private function createSlides($key, $answer, $data)
 {
    $slideIcons = [];

    foreach ($data[$key]["icons"] as $icon) {
        $slideIcons[] = $icon["preview_url"];
    }

    $keywords = $data[$key]['keywords'];
    $image_keywords = $data[$key]['image_keywords'];
    $images = $data[$key]['images'];
    $content = $this->addContent($keywords, $images);

    $this->presentation->slides()->create([
        'presentation_id' => $this->presentation->id,
        'pitch_answer_id' => $answer->id,
        'order' => $key,
        'keywords' => $keywords,
        'image_keywords' => $image_keywords,
        'images' => $images,
        'icons' => $slideIcons,
        'content' => $content
    ]);
}
```

And when I `var_dump($data[$key]["icons"])` (before the foreach loop) this is the result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(23) {
    ["attribution"]=>
    string(44) "people by Roman J. Sokolov from Noun Project"
    ["attribution_preview_url"]=>
    string(62) "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/attribution/2300-600.png"
    ["collections"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["date_uploaded"]=>
    string(10) "2012-04-26"
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "2300"
    ["is_active"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["is_explicit"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["license_description"]=>
    string(28) "creative-commons-attribution"
    ["nounji_free"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["permalink"]=>
    string(17) "/term/people/2300"
    ["preview_url"]=>
    string(54) "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2300-200.png"
    ["preview_url_42"]=>
    string(53) "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2300-42.png"
    ["preview_url_84"]=>
    string(53) "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2300-84.png"
  }
}
```

(There are more array elements that just that one, but they all have the same structure.)

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($data[$key]["icons"])`?

Comment: The $key comes from an other foreach?

Comment: If theres another foreach around there, you are resetting the array on every run ..

Comment: Put the `die(var_dump(($slideIcons)` after the foreach loop... otherways it will die before the variable is filled.

Comment: @GordonM I added the output.

Comment: It would probably help to isolate your issue to a smaller amount of code. To reproduce it with the smallest amount of code.

Comment: What do you get if you just dump the contents inside the loop? So: var_dump($slideIcons); (instead of die). Does the array go blank at any point? It should just get larger. Also try copy $data[$key]["icons"] into a variable first and then use that in the loop, does that make any difference?

Comment: @GuillermoPhillips For some reason, copying `$data[$key]["icons"]` into a variable did it! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Maybe your $data value is an object instead of an array? Then this behaviour would make sense, I guess.

If this is the case, the solution would be `foreach ($data->$key['icons'] as $icon)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim any solid reasoning behind this, just programmer's intuition, try:

```
$icons = $data[$key]["icons"];
foreach ($icons as $icon) {
    $slideIcons[] = $icon["preview_url"];
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why this would work. But somewhere in there there must be something low level to do with how the foreach is working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work